# Error When Setuping the WebRTC Native developement environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, webrtc

When setup the  webRTC native development environment in Ubuntu , I got the following error when executing `fetch webrtc`   ( Following instructions from http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/development)

```
> Error: Command '/usr/bin/python src/webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc
> -Dextra_gyp_flag=0' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/anoop/Documents/webrtcrepo Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "/home/anoop/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 342, in <module>
>     sys.exit(main())   File "/home/anoop/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 337, in main
>     return run(options, spec, root)   File "/home/anoop/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 331, in run
>     return checkout.init()   File "/home/anoop/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 142, in init
>     self.run_gclient(*sync_cmd)   File "/home/anoop/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 76, in run_gclient
>     return self.run(cmd_prefix + cmd, **kwargs)   File "/home/anoop/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 66, in run
>     return subprocess.check_output(cmd, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
>     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output) subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('gclient', 'sync',
> '--with_branch_heads')' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

**Update**

After running gclient sync directly I get following error

```
AssertionError: Point $JAVA_HOME or the java_home gyp variable to a directory containing include/jni.h!
gyp: Call to 'python -c "import os; dir=os.getenv('JAVA_HOME', '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64'); assert os.path.exists(os.path.join(dir, 'include/jni.h')), 'Point \$JAVA_HOME or the java_home gyp variable to a directory containing include/jni.h!'; print dir"' returned exit status 1
```

.

Comment: Did you install `depot_tools`, and is it in your `PATH`?

Comment: yes, depot_tools is in my path

Comment: To confirm that, if you run `gclient --help`, then you do get some useful output instead of e.g. command not found?

Comment: @rob gclient --help working.  This error happens after downloading ( Running: gclient sync ) around 2.6 GB of data.

Comment: Try running `fetch` again, and if that fails, try to run `gclient sync` directly. (and if you need even more information, `gclient sync --verbose`)

Comment: Rob, When I tried running gclient sync  the above error gets. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Did you install the JDK, and does the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable point to a directory containing `include/jni.h`?

Comment: I installed the JDK and set the JAVA_HOME. But how can environment variable point to a directory containing include/jni.h?

Comment: If `JAVA_HOME` is correctly set, then gclient sync should run without any issues. `stat "$JAVA_HOME/include/jni.h"` should show details about the file instead of "No such file or directory".

Comment: Thanks Rob, I installed open JDK , I think it needs oracle jdk.

Comment: OpenJDK works fine as well. Make sure that you install the JDK and not just the JRE.